# Script to clone a template folder retaing permissions and prompt for new folder name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt, file-permissions, xcopy

May I please get your insight?

I have a user group in AD call Contract Admin. I like would this user group to be able to run a script that clones a template folder (retaining permissions) to a new folder and prompt for a new client name.

The folder structure would be as follows:

- **Clients**

  - **New Folder** (template folder) (Permissions: Admins, Contract Admin, Financial Admin)

    - **Statements Folder** (Permissions: Financial Admin)

End result after script:

- **Clients**

  - **ABC Company** (Permissions: Admins, Contract Admin, Financial Admin)

    - **Statements Folder**  (Permissions: Financial Admin)

Above is an example of the folder structure where New Folder is the template folder which also has a folder inside of it as well. I'd like to have the folders cloned with permissions retained.

I hope this is clear, I apologize if it is not. Thank you so much for your help.

The code I currently have for copying the permissions are as folows:

robocopy /e /copy:DATS "X:\Template" "X:\New Folder Name"

attrib -h "Template"

This is what I have for cloning the folders but I am lost from here.
Thank you

**Solution:**
@echo off

set "src=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\template folder"

set /p "dest=Name of Client?: "

robocopy /e /copy:DATS %src% %dest%

---

the source can simply be the folder/file name without the full path if both the script and the folder/file to be copied is in the same directory.

/copy:   Specifies the file properties to be copied. The following are the valid values for this option:

- D Data A Attributes
- T Time stamps S NTFS access control list (ACL)
- O Owner information
- U Auditing information
- The default value for
- CopyFlags is DAT (data, attributes, and time stamps).

Comment: StackOverFlow was created to ask questions about code you are trying to use. Your question is off topic for this website.

Comment: My sincere apologies, I have added the coding that i started for the batch file.

Comment: I was able to use robocopy to accomplish the task:

Answer (score 0):

But this is not a script. It's a robocopy command.

There are many switches robocopy, [see its help file for them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

[Specifically the mirror (/MIR)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx) a folder tree to a new location.

As for prompting users, there are a few ways to do this. The most direct is [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6) cmdlet provides. You simply capture that in a variable and pass that as the folder.

```
$FolderPath = Read-Host 'Enter a folder path.'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give this a shot. I am new to this scripting and I think i have confused myself with robocopy.